# Material Design Lite: How to display Table on Mobile?

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I've got a big table that displays a lot of data.

On Destop it looks quite ok, but on mobile it just cuts of the data and I am not able to access what is on the table, like this:

**Desktop Version of Table**

[image: Table on Desktop]

**Mobile Version of Table**

[image]

Is there any way to make Tables accessible on Mobile? Or is the only way to just keep the data on a couple of rows only? And separate the columns on different cards?

(And yes, I know that this is not the best use for a card, I am still experimenting with mdl).

Thank you a lot.

Comment: As far as I know tables are not responsive just yet, so you might need to do some custom work to make it mobile-friendly.

Comment: Good table design (using all the bells and whistles as far as `tbody` and scope, etc) will probably still not "respond", but it will be semantically well-built in a way that should make it more future-proof (for the native browser solutions that we know are coming around some day), as well as easier to parse/scan/consume for add-on solutions (like using newer HTML templating / Shadow DOM / some js-based solution / etc. So still best to make the table semantic and "true" and then focus on presentation.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 3):

If this is not late you can use this trick to make it responsive

https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: Points for linking the exact article I thought of when I saw the title on this question. I'm still on the fence regarding vertical table output being the best solution, but its definitely one of the more sensible and visually appealing options.

Comment: there more option to article mentioned above, check out Flip Scroll for better option [Responsive Filp Scroll](http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/)